# Unable to programmatically expand TreeNode that is assigned to a TreeView

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview, c++-cli, .net-1.1

I am working with C++ and .NET 1.1. I have an issue with programmatically expanding TreeNode objects once they are assigned to a TreeView. When running the following code in debug mode:

```
TreeView* myTreeView = new TreeView();
TreeNode* myTreeNode = new TreeNode();
myTreeNode->Expand();
myTreeView->Nodes->Add(myTreeNode);
myTreeNode->Expand();
```

I can see that the `IsExpanded` property of `myTreeNode` is set to `true` when doing the first `Expand()`, but when the node is added to `myTreeView` `IsExpanded` is set to `false`, and the second `Expand()` has no effect at all.

Can anyone explain this behavior? I'm thinking there is a setting for the TreeView or something similar, but I haven't been able to find anything like that, and from the example code MS provides this should work just fine, so I'm probably missing something pretty obvious...

Comment: I have done this many times in C# and .NET 2 and confirm it works perfectly there. Perhaps a bug?

Comment: What is the reason to use .NET 1.1 in 2011?!? Use at least 2.0

Comment: You can't expand a node without children:

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242647/empty-expandable-treenode-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a myTreeNode->Collapse() before calling the expand. It could be that the node thinks it is expanded when it is not and so calling expand will just be ignored because the node thinks it is already expanded anyway...

```
  TreeView* myTreeView = new TreeView();
  TreeNode* myTreeNode = new TreeNode();
  myTreeNode->Expand();
  myTreeView->Nodes->Add(myTreeNode);
  myTreeNode->Collapse();
  myTreeNode->Expand();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried listening for the [TreeView.AfterCollapse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercollapse%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) event to see if someone else is collapsing the [TreeNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) after you add it to the [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)?